# Grid inside button won't stretch horizontally

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Given the following markup, I would have expected the chevron to go all the way to the right of the button, but it doesn't - instead, the stack panel and the chevron are tight together in the middle of the button.

```
<Button Background="Teal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="60">Click!</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="20">Cool things will happen</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   FontSize="60"
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol">
            &#xe013; <!-- unicode for chevron right in this font -->
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

[image: Chevron should be all the way to the right]

Comment: Did you try to set the HorizontalContentAlignment of the button to Stretch?

Comment: @Max: Apparently not - thanks a lot! Type it in an answer and I'll give you some rep for it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set the [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the button to `Stretch`.